# error no matching function for call to 'student::student()'

Tags: c++, oop

there is an error in the constructor in `studentPhD` class, and here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class student{
    protected:
        string name;
        int id;
        int level;
        int i;
    public:
        student(string N, int I, int L){
            name = N;
            id = I;
            level = L;
        }
        
        int getId(){
            return id;
        }
        
        int getLevel(){
            return level;
        }
        
        virtual void display(){
            cout << "the name of student is: " << name << endl;
            cout << "the id of student is: " << id << endl;
            cout << "the level of the student is: " << level << endl;
        }
};

class studentPhD : public student{
    private:
        string specialty;
        string supervisorName;
        
    public:
        studentPhD(string s, string sN){
            specialty = s;
            supervisorName = sN;
            
        }
        
        void display(){
            cout << "the specialty is: " << specialty << endl;
            cout << "the supervisor name is: " << supervisorName << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    student a("A", 123, 4);
    student b("B", 124, 5);
    
    a.display();
    cout << endl;
    b.display();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
<source>: In constructor 'studentPhD::studentPhD(std::string, std::string)':
<source>:39:48: error: no matching function for call to 'student::student()'
   39 |                 studentPhD(string s, string sN){
      |                                                ^
<source>:12:17: note: candidate: 'student::student(std::string, int, int)'
   12 |                 student(string N, int I, int L){
      |                 ^~~~~~~
<source>:12:17: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
<source>:5:7: note: candidate: 'student::student(const student&)'
    5 | class student{
      |       ^~~~~~~
<source>:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
<source>:5:7: note: candidate: 'student::student(student&&)'
<source>:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to **[edit]** your questions to improve them, like for example copy-paste (as text!) your [mre] and the error it generates into the question itself. You should always keep questions *self-contained*.

Comment: Describe your error and paste code with minimal reproduce example

Comment: Please post a code block here verbatim, not pictures. Thanks for announcing that there is an error, but could you please state your question?

Comment: studentPhD derives from Student, so its constructor must call the Student constructor to initialize the base class.

Comment: just add line to to the body of student class ```student() = default;```

Comment: Since `studentPhD` *is-a* `student`, any construction of a `studentPhD` object also needs to construct and initialize the `student` part. That means your `studentPhD` constructor will contain an implicit call to the `student` default constructor. But `student` doesn't have a default constructor, only some other constructor which is not possible to use. Either add a constructor initializer list in the `studentPhD` constructor that explicitly call the only available `student` constructor (the one with arguments). Or create a `student` default constructor.

Comment: @Deumaudit Or delete `class studentPhD` entirely. It would be just as correct.